# Facebook Messenger API message sequence

Tags: javascript, facebook

When I post a series of messages to the messenger API (https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=MYTOKEN), the messages are not received by the recipient in the same order. For example (in pseudocode):

`sendMessage('1');
sendMessage('2');
sendMessage('3');`

The recipient sometimes gets [1,2,3] but can also get [3,1,2], [2,1,3], etc.

Comment: What does sendMessage do?

Comment: @WizKid sendMessage Posts to facebook/messages. For example: `function sendMessage(messageData) {
  let qs = "?access_token=" + PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN;
  fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages' +  qs, 
  { method: 'POST', 
    body: JSON.stringify(messageData),
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(function(res) {
      return res.json();
  })
}`

Comment: So of course it will not work. You sending message 2 before message one have been sent. Wait until message 1 is sent before you send message 2

Comment: If I send the messages in sequential order they occasionally show up on the messenger side out of sequence.  @WizKid

Comment: Yes of course. You are doing 3 async requests. You need to wait and send the second message until the first message is sent

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution which works for me but may not be scalable. Hopefully, it helps you.

```
var sendMessagesToUser = function (messages, sessionId) {
  let session = sessionsManager.getSessionBySessionId(sessionId);
  messages.forEach(function (message, index) {

    //Delay or queue messages so we'll keep order in place
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(message)
      switch (message.type) {
        case sessionsManager.MESSAGE_TYPES.CUSTOME:
          utility.sendCustomMessage(session.userId, message.payload.facebook);
          break;
        case sessionsManager.MESSAGE_TYPES.TEXT:
          utility.sendTextMessage(session.userId, message.speech || message.text);
          break;
        case sessionsManager.MESSAGE_TYPES.CARD:
          utility.sendGenericMessage(session.userId, message.title, message.subtitle, message.imageUrl, message.buttons);
          break;
        case sessionsManager.MESSAGE_TYPES.QUICK_REPLY:
          utility.sendQuickReply(session.userId, message.title, message.replies);
          break;
      }
    }, 1000 * index);
  })
};
```